# How to have report displayed in sonarqube only for some specific files

Tags: testing, coding-style, sonarqube, jacoco

I am a beginner using sonarqube to analyze multiple java programs. However I would like Sonarqube to report issues/coverage (using jacoco) only in some source files and not the others.

Currently, I have set up jacoco to check coverage only of that file. I tried using the `sonar.exclusions`,  `sonar.inclusions`. But these result in either all or none the source files being ignored (the report is not selective as I want it to be). I also tried using `sonar.issue.ignore.allfile` but none of these seem to work.

So, what would be the best way to achieve what I describe?

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube lets you define *Coverage Exclusions* (`sonar.coverage.exclusions`) to *exclude files/directories from Coverage calculations but analyze all other aspects* (source: SonarQube documentation on [Narrowing the Focus](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)).